# How to modify `numpy` code and rebuild and use it?

Tags: python, numpy, build

Normally, my `numpy` is located on

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy
```

And i download the new one from website to modify some function of numpy then build and install it.

For this `modified numpy` is located on

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
```

And, my `$PYTHONPATH` had both

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

and

`/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

I think this is confusing.

My question is how can i use my `modified numpy` instead of the original numpy in my project?

Finally, My point is i just want to use my `modified numpy` in my project. And in the same time i don't want to mixed up my modified code to the original code of numpy. What's the best way to manage the multiple version of numpy?

Comment: have you tried virtualenv?

Comment: I have tried. i knew how to switch the version of numpy but i did't know how to switch `numpy` to my `modified numpy`.  if you want to answer you don't need to stick to my setup you can recommend me a right way to modified code and use it. with out any confusing of many version of code.

Comment: can you reinstall and modify again?

Answer (score 1):

The following commands are for a unix based OS which should obviously work for you on mac.

1. Install `virtualenv` with `pip`
2. Use `virtualenv my_proj_name` to create your venv.
3. Then `cd my_proj_name` and enter`. bin/activate`
4. You can `pip install numpy` and rebuild/modify  or copy  your modified `numpy` to `my_proj_name/lib/python2.7`.
5. import it and use it, your virtualenv packages will be completely separate from any system packages

If you don't have pip installed:
Download the `get-pip.py` script and run it with `python get_pip.py`.

Comment: I tried already step up following your guide. On step 4 i moved my `modified numpy` (already rebuild) from outsite to `my_proj_name/lib/python2.7` but when i try to use numpy my modified code still didn't work. it seem like python still pointed on the original numpy package not on `my_proj_name/lib/python2.7`

Comment: you have to activate your venv environment and build your project inside.